# What is the best source to learn how to fully integrate Rails' polymorphic associations into your application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphic-associations

I want to know not only how to set up your models, but also how to construct your controllers and whatever else necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association